# how to describe correctly about a 5D tensor? (keras, r)

Tags: r, keras

In the introduction page of `layer_conv_3d` [layer_conv_3d](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/layer_conv_3d.html), it gave an example as ' e.g. input_shape=c(128L, 128L, 128L, 3L) for 128x128x128 volumes with a single channel, in data_format="channels_last".'

shouldn't it be a 3 channels cubic of 128L*128L*128L? if `c(128L, 128L, 128L, 3L)` is to describe a single channel cubic, how to describe a 3 channels one? Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that document is wrong, it represents a 3-channel cube, a one channel cube would have shape `(w, h, d, 1)`.

Comment: a following question: I read a book suggesting to use conv_3d for RGB image. In that way, it shoulbe be reshape to (w, h, 1, 3), and conv with kernal of (3,3,1), say, right?